# Changing the background color of Ultra Win Grid

Tags: infragistics, windows-forms-designer, ultrawingrid

I want to change the color of the background of the grid.

What i tried is

```
MyGrid.DisplayLayout.Appearance.BackColor = Color.White;
```

But its not working, it stays with the same color as before. 
Ive checked in the debugger and the object has the correct value on that property, the problem is for some reason the grid is not being correctly painted.

Ive also tried calling the ResetDisplayLayout() function, to confirm if the color that was being painted was the default one and it was.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Under Properties for your grid, create an event for InitializeLayout and put it there:

```
    private void MyGrid_InitializeLayout(object sender, InitializeLayoutEventArgs e)
    {
        MyGrid.DisplayLayout.Appearance.BackColor = Color.White;
    }
```

Comment: This did not work. Still displaying a light gray colour.

Comment: uhhhh, something is not right. That should work. If you debug and put a breakpoint on that line, does it get reached?

Comment: Yes, and ive checked consistently that the property backcolor has always this value. I add some info i gathered today; if i do a printscreen the grid is white in the generated image in both monitors i have. Also, while using the windows form, on one monitor is noticeably different (its light gray), in the other monitor the same grid is almost white, i have to watch the monitor sideways to spot the difference in the color (between the grid color and the background color which is white).

Do you have any idea what could be causing this behavior?

Comment: It sounds like a monitor or graphics card issue. Does changing the color to something higher contrast like green make a difference? How are you doing the print screen? Is it the screen or your application window?

Comment: If it doesn't work, it may depend on a flag called 'ResolutionOrder'. Try to edit grid settings using AppStylist and change ResolutionOrder to "ControlThenApplication".

Answer (score 0):

Try one of the following:

1) In your grid properties set UseAppStyling to false
2) Add a new appearance to the DisplayLayout.Appearances collection, then in code set the grid to use that Appearance

Option two would be the best bet, as otherwise you'll lose any other standard settings, which might make this grid look different to the others in your project.

Are you using a style library? We are, and I need to do one of the above to make the system override the default styles defined in that library. Even if you're not, it may well be that there is a default style library in effect.

Comment: Yes! its my problem exactly. I have a style library but i dont want to stop using it and i need to use appstyling becuase otherwise the grids look awful. I tried the option 2 but did not work. What is the exact property i need to override in displaylayout.override?

Comment: Okay, you need to go to the Appearances collection in DisplayLayout and add a new appearance with the settings you require (I just set the background colour to a random colour). Next select the "Appearance" property and you should be able to select your appearance from the drop down list. I've found I need to do this from the custom settings dialog for the grid, it doesn't work from the properties window. That should be all it takes